# Does Qt-Creator have support for Unit Tests?

Tags: c++, c, qt, unit-testing, qt-creator

I started off using Qt-Creator to try out programming qt, but i've also noticed that its a very good IDE for coding in C and C++.

Over the past few months I have been trying out and noticing the benefits of test-driven development when programming in Python through these of frameworks like [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which is supported in the [pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE.

Does C++ and C have an equivalent test framework that can be used in Qt Creator? If not, is there some other IDE I can try that supports the same (or similar) integration that pycharm offers?

Comment: [do you mean this?](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial1.html)

Comment: Thats pretty much on the lines I want. Is there something more general for C and C++ which doesnt require Qt libraries?

Comment: Well, there is [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/), which is Google's framework for writing C++ tests.

Comment: These are both very good and exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it does. You can read about how to make unit tests on QT using their [`QTestLib tutorial`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-tutorial.html).

If you want a framework that doesn't require the use of Qt libraries, you can use [`googletest`](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/), which is a Google's  framework and run under many enviroments (like *mLinux, Mac OS X, Windows, Cygwin, Windows CE, and Symbian* - taken from googletest docs)

Also, if you want to know about more C++ Unit Testing frameworks, you can take a look at the [`wikipedia page`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B). There are plenty of options over there.

Answer (score 2):

there is library [QTestLib](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qtestlib-manual.html).

Citing from QtCreator documentation:

> The QTestLib framework, provided by Nokia, is a tool for unit testing Qt based applications and libraries. QTestLib provides all the functionality commonly found in unit testing frameworks as well as extensions for testing graphical user interfaces.

I'm still using 4.8 on Linux....